# UEFI HTTP Network Boot

Tags: networking, uefi, netboot

What is the correct *syntax* or *structure* when having to manually create an UEFI HTTP Boot entry ?

i.e.

```
bcfg boot add 5 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x13,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(123456789AB,0x0)/IPv6(::/128,0,Static,::/128,::/128,0)/Uri()
```

will fails with "Cannot open file"

** Noted:

- UEFI Boot Manager does not support manual boot options.
- UEFI 2.60 implementation